# Embedding dropdown menu with custom datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have created a windows application which retrieve data from .dat file and convert it into datagridview(as per my requirement, it splits data into columns).Now column named "Grouptype" is there. I want to create a dropdownbox in that particular column. and it should be filled with the existing data of that column. 
E.g. if there are 5 different values for Grouptype column then the dropdownbox should be filled by those values. and if i add any new row and grouptype column has any new value then it should be allowed to enter.

For binding purpose i have used following code.

```
public static SortableBindingList<User> LoadUserListFromBkpFile(string path)
{
    var users = new SortableBindingList<User>();
    char[] delimiterChars = { '|' };
    foreach (var linedata in File.ReadAllLines(path))
    {
        string[] words = linedata.Split(delimiterChars);
        if (words.Count() < 10)
        {
            return users;
        }
        if (words[0].Trim() != "")
        {
            users.Add(new User
            {
                LineNumber = int.Parse(words[0]),
                GroupType = words[1],
                CountyCode = words[2],
                County = words[3],
                Payee = words[4],
                Address1 = words[5],
                Address2 = words[6],
                City = words[7],
                State = words[8],
                ZipCode = words[9]
            });
        }
    }
    return users;  
}
```